# jQuery SimpleModal Showing scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, simplemodal

I have a pretty basic problem I can't figure out when using jQuery simplemodal: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Here is a jsfiddle that illustrates: http://jsfiddle.net/F5tN9/1/

I want to click a link (see the "Click me" link), and show a modal dialog.  However, if I have too much text in the dialog, SimpleModal is resizing the box to be too small so there ends up being scrollbars.  I wasn't sure the best way to solve this (maybe force the element height to auto in a callback?), but I figured that this was a pretty basic example and there must be some solution or reason as to why it doesn't work right.

Comment: so you do not want to have a scroll bar no matter how long the text is, right?

Comment: Yes, I want the modal box to just expand its height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#click').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#modal_soon').modal({
            overlayClose : true,
            containerCss: {'height': 'auto !important'}
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you add in the css : #simplemodal-container {height:auto!important}?

Comment: @chchrist I thought I had tried that, I guess not because it works as well.